# I am trying to make a Microsoft Sharepoint page using HTML and CSS. The image wont center in different browsers

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I am trying to put this image in the left container but it seems to leak out in chrome and not in explorer.

```css
  .left-col p{
                           text-align: justify;
                           width:300px;
                                       }                           

                  .left-col img{
                              margin: 0 auto;
                              left: 10%;
                              width:300px; 
                              height: 130px;
                              text-align:center;
                               }
```

```html
<div class="left-col">
      <img src="Cyber.jpg" width="200" height=150"/>
             <p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec iaculis neque nec luctus maximus. Donec eu eleifend libero, nec scelerisque metus. Morbi volutpat turpis pretium </p>
```

```css
.container div {
   padding: 1%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   min-height: 700px;
  }
                  .left-col p{
                           text-align: justify;
                           width:300px;
                                       }                           

                  .left-col img{
                              margin: 0 auto;
                              left: 10%;
                              width:300px; 
                              height: 130px;
                              text-align:center;
                               }

  .left-col, .right-col {
   background-color: #f4f4f4;
   width: 25%;
   float: left;
  }
  .center-col {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
  }
```

```html
</div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="left-col">
      <img src="Cyber.jpg" width="200" height=150"/>
             <p><p>Lorem  pretium </p>
 </div>
 <div class="center-col">
  <h2>Center</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolortempor.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="right-col">
  <h2>Right</h2>
  <p>Lorem tempor.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image: Chrome]
[image: Explorer]

Comment: Most of your issues are with code formatting, lots of your `height:` attributes only have one `"` and thus are breaking your entire code. What you are trying to achieve is not immediately obvious either.

Comment: @Laif I am not sure what " means, I am starting off with HTML and CSS

Comment: It is a quotation mark.. You put `<img src="Cyber.jpg" width="200" height=150"/>` several times when it needs to be `<img src="Cyber.jpg" width="200" height="150"/>` with a `"` before _and_ after the attribute (150px).

Comment: Is it just the image leaking out? or text as well?.... maybe consider adding a clearfix div just before the closing of your main container div `clear:both;`

Comment: @JCBiggar Just the Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example code for your reference.

```
<style>
.container{ 
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
.container div{
    min-height: 700px;
    height:100%;
    padding: 1%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.left-col p{
    text-align: justify;
    width:270px;
}                           

.left-col img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 10%;
    width:270px; 
    height: 130px;
    text-align:center;
}
.center-col {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 300px;
    float:left;
}
.left-col{
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
.right-col {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="left-col">
        <img src="Cyber.jpg" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec iaculis neque nec luctus maximus. Donec eu eleifend libero, nec scelerisque metus. Morbi volutpat turpis pretium </p>
    </div>
    <div class="center-col">
        <h2>Center</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec iaculis neque nec luctus maximus. Donec eu eleifend libero, nec scelerisque metus. Morbi volutpat turpis pretium</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
        <h2>Right</h2>
        <p>Lorem tempor.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]